# how to escape backslash in ant

Tags: ant

I am writing Ant scripts.

I have a property which has the value: 
    "C\:Program Files\\test1\\test2"

Is there a method in Ant to convert it to:
    C:Program Files\test1\test2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use : http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/propertyregex.html

although I am not sure if this will do what you are asking for. Are the backslashes visible when you echo your property?

In any case to use the above task you will have to have ant-contrib installed and simply write a task like this :

```
<project name="test" default="build">
<!--Needed for antcontrib-->
<taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml"/>

<target name="build">

    <property name="path" value="C\:Program Files\\test1\\test2"/>
    <echo message="Path with slashes : ${path}"/>
    <propertyregex  property="removed.backslash.property"
                input="${path}"
                global="true"
                regexp="\\(\\|:)"
                replace="\1"
    />
    <echo message="Path with single slashes : ${removed.backslash.property}"/>
</target>

</project>
```

Output :

```
build:
 [echo] Path with slashes : C\:Program Files\\test1\\test2
 [echo] Path with single slashes : C:Program Files\test1\test2
```

In addition you could use any of the BSF languages :

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html

provided you are using jre 1.6 and above.

Comment: When echo, the backslashes are visible, I also tried your solution. It seems that your regex has some problems?

Comment: Please try the updated answer. It should work right out of the box :)

Comment: Almost there, I want "\:" to be converted to ":". See my org post.

Comment: Great thanks a lot. I am not very good at regex. Can you please explain how the regex works?

Comment: Really appreciate. Can you look at my other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7683397/how-to-replace-a-backslash-in-some-lines-of-a-text-in-ant