# how to replace a backslash in some lines of a text in Ant

Tags: java, regex, ant

Using

```
<replaceregexp byline="true" flags="g" file="${someFIle}"
              match = "[\\]"
              replace = "/"/>
```

I can easily replace all the \ with /.

But

Suppose the text is:

```
Other A\B\C
Some C\D\E
Other ...
Other ...
...
```

How to replace the "\" with "/" in the second line which has prefix "Some", but not other lines:

```
Other A\B\C
Some C/D/E
...
```

Comment: is it meant to be alternating in lines for the replace?

Comment: @performanceuser Is the input a text from a property or a file?

Comment: Should better to be considered as a file, but it is actually a properties file. What I am trying to do is for some properties, I want to convert \ to /, otherwise Ant will eat the "\".

Comment: What I am trying to do is if user put single "\" to a property, I need to escape it to "\\" or just convert it to "/".

Comment: @performanceuser Is A\B\C guaranteed to have this format? Or is it possible that there are more slashes and not only 3?

Comment: No, maybe more slashes. Sometimes A\B or A\B\c\D

Comment: My purpose is to avoid the escape. When Ant read the properties file, it will eat up one "\", I just need to avoid this. So I choose to convert "\" to "/", or maybe to "\\" is better

Answer (score 0):

`replaceregexp` does not have options to skip lines.

Comment: What I really need is a regex that I can use. Once I figure that out, I think it would be easy to apply to ANt

Comment: You have `byline="true"`, it will execute line by line and it won't skip on others.

Comment: Is there a way to specify some prefix in regex? So that regex can match the prefix to skip lines?

Comment: Yes, "Line1" is part of the text

Answer (score 0):

Your problem cannot be merely solved by a single regex. You need to do something more complex.

1) Read properties only with the specified prefix and save them to variable. This can be done with propertyregex.

2) Read all other properties and save them somewhere.

3) Replace \ with whatever you want in the properties which contain the prefix.

4) Write the modified properties with the properties without the prefix into a file replacing the original file.

5) Enjoy :-)

Try to do these steps one by one. If you still have questions let me know.

Comment: It won't work. I need to replace the \ before reading it as a property. In step 1, when I read it, the \ have been eaten by Ant

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with the property once you read it?