# Escaping Backslash in Ant + Multiple directories compilation

Tags: java, ant

I have already checked this question and did not find my answer. [how to escape backslash in ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655609/how-to-escape-backslash-in-ant)

I'm trying to compile my `.java` files which exist in multiple directories. 
Example: This is my folder structure:

```
->testprojects
    ->com.junit.abc
         ->src
            ->junit tests to run

    ->com.junit.bcd
        ->src
            ->junit tests to run

    ->com.junit.xyz
        ->src
            ->junit tests to run

    ->com.junit.pqr
        ->src
            ->junit tests to run
```

The script must locate all files in the src folders and compile it.
So I've created a `dirset` of all the directories where the files are present.
I just need to append the name of the drive to it for it to become a proper path
like

> "D:\" +"NEON\HW\testprojects\src"

but I need to escape my backslash in order for the path to work.

prop.dist.contents is the rest of the path

snippet of my build.xml :

```
<dirset id="dist.contents" dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*junit*/src"/> 
<property name="prop.dist.contents" refid="dist.contents"/>
<echo>${prop.dist.contents}</echo>  

<target name="compile">
    <delete dir="${classes.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir} \${prop.dist.contents}" destdir="${classes.dir}" includeantruntime="false" debug="true">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="ALL.jars"/>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <pathelement location="D:/NEON/HW/CodeCheck/lib/javaparser-core-3.2.5.jar"/>
            <pathelement location="C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111/jre/lib/rt.jar"/>
        </classpath>
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
        <compilerarg line="-Xmaxerrs 10000" />
    </javac>
    <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.properties" />
    </copy>     
</target
```

But this for some reason links `prop.dist.contents` to the location of my build.xml(working directory)

Error received:

```
C:\JUnit\apache-ant-1.10.1\build.xml:46: srcdir "C:\JUnit\apache-ant-1.10.1\com.**.junit\src" does not exist!
```

**Question:**

1. How can I escape the backslash for the path to work?
2. Will this method work? Will Ant be able to compile java files from multiple directories like this? If not, is there any suitable alternative?

Comment: Did you try to use a `/`? If I remember correctly, java convert the path to the correct path of the OS.

Comment: @baudsp Yes, I tried using the forward slash. Still doesn't work for me. Is there any other way?

Comment: I don't know. I've just checked the build.xml files we use to build on Windows and I saw that we are using \ and / for the paths.

Comment: What's the value of src.dir? Can't you just put the path with D:/ right when defining this property?